# web project only close session in filter and service and dao do not close session

Tags: hibernate

Now I have worked on a legacy web project， used spring mvc(spring 4.0.5)and hibernate(3.3.2 GA), I found some service and dao explicitly close session in the end, e.g.

```
public City getCityByCityId(Integer cityId) {
    Session s = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
    City city = cityDAO.getById(City.class, cityId, s);
    s.close(); // after getting the result explicitly close the session
    return city;
}
```

but others not and session is put in threadLocal.

```
public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
    if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
        // build session
         threadLocal.set(session);
    }
    return session;
}
```

In additional I found in a filter , after called `chain.doFilter(...)`, still call close session globaly, e.g.

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //......
}
try{
    //avoid forgettig to close session
    HibernateSessionFactory.closeSession();
}catch(Exception e){
    log.error("close session in filter failed",e);
}
```

Right now I encountered below problem, that is when I call a query method(it explicitly close session) innner a transaction, e.g.

```
Session s = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
Transaction beginTransaction = s.beginTransaction();
try {
    usOrderDAO.save(order, s);
    City city = cityService.getCityByCityId(order.getCity()); // in this query it will close session
    addOrderBusinessDistricts(order, city, s);
    //...
    beginTransaction.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //...
} finally {
    s.close();
}
```

it will throw exception:

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:72)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createSQLQuery(SessionImpl.java:1655)
```

the cause is that closed session before executing commit.

So now for solving my above problem I want to delete all those `s.close();` code in service and dao, anyway in the end in filter it will close the session. But I'm not very sure if could cause some potential bug. How to assess the risk?

Comment: try and see..if it works first

Comment: but it has bean running in production environment, I don't dare

Comment: woha.,so you gonna attempt a hot fix on production?Good luck